# Enable only specific weekday dates and disable all dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime, ionic-framework

I am developing an application in Ionic framework by using `720kb/angular-datepicker` datepicker plugin.I want to disable all dates and enable only specifc weekday dates in a year.

```
 <datepicker style="top:10%; " date-disabled-dates="{{disabledDates}}" date-min-limit="{{dateMin}}" date-enabled-dates="{{enabledDates}}">
                <input ng-model="dateobj.date" type="text" ng-hide="true"  />
  </datepicker>
```

its working fine to disable my custom dates, but i want to disable all days 
except Monday and Tuesday , and then enable some days.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Controller code

```
    $scope.disabledDates = []

    Appointment.getAnnualHolidayDays().success(function (res) {
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                var currentDate = new Date(res[i].StartDate);
                var endDate = new Date(res[i].EndDate);
                var j = 0;
                if (currentDate == endDate) {
                    j = j + 1;
                    $scope.disabledDates.push($filter("date")(currentDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy'));
                } else {
                    while (currentDate < endDate) {
                        j = j + 1;
                        currentDate = new Date(currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1));
                        $scope.disabledDates.push(new Date($filter("date")(currentDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd')));
                        // console.log((j) + (i) + '->' + $filter("date")(currentDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy'));
                    }
                }
            }

     localStorageService.set("disabledDates", $scope.disabledDates);

  });
```

Comment: So in addition of your current disabled date (by your code) you want to enable only monday & tuesday, and enable some date you defined?

Comment: @FetraR. yes i want to enable only Monday and Tuesday date of all months